# R Programming - if condition execution

Tags: r

I am executing following code in R using  "IF" and the condition executed (I was expecting, it will give error message),

```
if("TRUE") print("ok")
```

can some one help me in understanding the logic behind the code execution?

My understanding is that "if statement" will execute when the conditional expression is true.

In the above code, I have given character as input, but the if condition is executed, which surprise me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some context by editing your question to include a) your code in more detail (formatted using the {} button), b) what you expect to see, c) what you see in practice, d) any error messages you are getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

R converts the argument of `if` statement if it is interpretable as logical. In this case `"TRUE"` is interpretable as logical. Please see that `as.logical("TRUE")` returns `TRUE`. However,  `if("HELLO") print("ok")` would not work and you will get the error:

> Error in if ("HELLO") print("ok") :
>     argument is not interpretable as logical

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the error in your syntax. Try this:

```
if (TRUE){
  print("ok")
}
```